# How to Write Matrix data to Excel Julia?

Tags: julia, xlsx

I have variables that stored in julia notebook called
`sheet1 = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]` and `sheet2 = [1 1 1; 2 2 2]`

how do i write this variable into excel workbook with a different worksheet?

and how if i want in a same worksheet?

`xlxs.addsheet!` didnt work , tq

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer a one liner this can be done as:

```
XLSX.writetable("file.xlsx",
    sheet1=(collect(eachcol(sheet1)), 'a':'c'), 
    sheet2=(collect(eachcol(sheet2)), string.("col", 1:3)) )
```

Comment: Thankyou for u answer, but can u make it simple? without adding some string or array again. my goal is

write the matrics sheet 1 and sheet 2 in different workspace with same shape and everytime i change the variable it doesnt need to delete the file.xlsx to run my program.

Im sorry if it didn't clear, my goal actually , i just want to extract value from variable to excel

Comment: If you want more control, you need to start with code by @cbk. I think it is quite self explanatory

Answer (score 2):

Modifying an example from the [documentation](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/tutorial/),

```
using XLSX

filename = "myfile.xlsx"

# Some example data to try writing to .xlsx
columns = Vector()
push!(columns, [1, 2, 3])
push!(columns, ["a", "b", "c"])
labels = [ "column_1", "column_2"]

XLSX.openxlsx(filename, mode="w") do xf
    sheet = xf[1]
    # Write our data to sheet 1
    XLSX.writetable!(sheet, columns, labels, anchor_cell=XLSX.CellRef("A1"))
    # Write the same data, but to a different place in the sheet
    XLSX.writetable!(sheet, columns, labels, anchor_cell=XLSX.CellRef("D1"))
    # Add a new sheet, which we will then access with xf[2]
    XLSX.addsheet!(xf)
    # Write the same data, but to sheet 2, in yet another position
    XLSX.writetable!(xf[2], columns, labels, anchor_cell=XLSX.CellRef("B2"))
end
```

You were on the right track with `XLSX.addsheet!`, but have to then write to that second sheet, the reference to which is stored in the second position of `xf` in this example. This example also shows how to write to different positions within the same sheet, using the `anchor_cell` keyword option.

Comment: Thankyou for u answer, but can u make it simple? without adding some string or array again. my goal is write the matrics sheet 1 and sheet 2 in different workspace with same shape and everytime i change the variable it doesnt need to delete the file.xlsx to run my program. Im sorry if it didn't clear, my goal actually , i just want to extract value from variable to excel

Comment: Yes, you just need to replace `columns` with your `sheet1` and `sheet2`, and replace `labels` with whatever labels you would like the data in your `sheet1`  or `sheet2` variables to have.